# Unable to set java heap space > 2GB on Win2008 64bit

Tags: java, jenkins, jvm, jvm-arguments

Unable to set java heap space using `-Xmx` to `2GB` or more even though the `RAM` size is `16GB`.

I encounter an error saying "

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit"
```

This is seen while starting a Jenkins server on my `Win2008 x64 machine.`

Please let me know if I could change any system parameter which will allow me to allocate more memory.

Thanks

Comment: Which command did you use? Are you sure that your java is not 32-bit version?

Comment: Simple java command with arguments "-Xrs -Xmx2048m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8090". Java is 64bit version but Jenkins application is 32bit one receding in "Program Files  x86"

Comment: Even though you have a 64-bit version of Java installed, your jenkins is using a 32-bit version.

Comment: Do you really have -Xmx with 2BG and not 2GB?

Comment: sorry! just a typo error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the fix with the help of clue given above by Neil.

Here is the full details:

Even though the machine is installed with JDK 1.7 x64 bit, Jenkins by default is not configured with this version available on the machine.

Jenkins has its own JRE bundled with the installer which is used by default.

To change it to a different JDK edit the Jenkins.xml file and modify the below value

```
<executable>jre\bin\java</executable>
```

to

```
<executable><jdk install path>\bin\java</executable>
```

This is now solved!!

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
java -version
```

and check you see

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

I expect you have a 32 bit version of java which is limited to 2 GB (as its not large address aware)

Comment: Yes I see "java version "1.7.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)"

Comment: Start jenkins with the default arguments and go to http://jenkinsserver/systemInfo and see what java its really using.  It could have picked the system default if you start it as a service.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot, it had something to do with the java it is referring to. Have the changed the XML file to get it done..! If dont mind can i edit your answer and add more details for the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Use "java -version" to ensure that your java hotspot is a 64-bit server vm.

Comment: I see this "java version "1.7.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)"

Answer (score 0):

theoretical limit for maximum heap size on 32 bit JVM is 4GB and for 64 bit JVM its 2^64

For more detail [Click here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/04/what-is-maximum-heap-size-for-32-bit-64-JVM-Java-memory.html)

Comment: Java 32 bit is not large address aware so it cannot use the highest bit by default so its limited to 2Gb.